# Python 3.2.5.1 input limit? 255 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I'm currently coding an encoder and decoder, and when a complex key is used to code the message, the coded message is well over 255 characters long, however when I paste it into the input bar, it cuts it off at 255 characters. Any way to get around this? I'm using `input()`, which works the exact same as what `raw_input()` did on older versions.

Comment: What kind of terminal are you using?  I'd blame that before Python.

Comment: I just tried the usual python terminal in linux and it didn't have this problem.